# Python append an item in a list to another list and pop the last element in the original one

Tags: python, list, append

I have two lists, I want to take each element from one list append it to another list and save the result in yet another list. This is my code, but when I append the item and assign the result to another list, then the pop removes the appended item from both the original list and the result list.

```
pi = [['Shirt','Red'],['Shirt','Blue']]
sizes = ['XS','S']
result = []
for item in pi:
    for size in sizes:
        item.append(size)
        result.append(item)
        item.pop(-1) #Once this line is run the size is removed from both result and item
```

My end goal is to have the result list like this:

```
result=[[['Shirt','Red','XS'],['Shirt','Red','S'],['Shirt','Blue','XS'],['Shirt','Blue','S']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember well, the problem was the pass by reference, you have to append a copy of the list.

```
pi = [['Shirt','Red'],['Shirt','Blue']]
sizes = ['XS','S']
result = []
for item in pi:
    for size in sizes:
        item.append(size)
        result.append(item[:])
        item.pop(-1)
print(result)
```

[Results of running that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZuHN.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a *copy* of the list when you add it to the result, otherwise modifications made to one will occur in the other as well.

```
result.append(list(item))
```

In this case, the only reason you `pop` is to undo the modification you just did, so it's better to just do it to the copy instead.

```
copy = item[:]
copy.append(size)
result.append(copy)
```

Comment: Is there any other better way to approach this problem? As you said I need to undo the modification each time, and I actually have 3 lists that needs the same algorithm for each item.

Comment: @payam sorry, my example was incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

```
pi = [['Shirt','Red'],['Shirt','Blue']]
sizes = ['XS','S']
result = []
for i in pi:
  for j in sizes:
    result.append(i+[j])

print result
```

This should do it

Answer (score 1):

this is referance problem, use copy()

```
result.append(item.copy())
```

Comment: I have been trying to solve this for 3hours! It was of great help! Thanks!